# Message Driven Bean (MDB) running on Websphere Application Server, leaves channel connections open

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

Hi
I have two Message Driven Beans (MDBs) running on Websphere Application Server v7.
It is connecting to, and receiving messages from Websphere MQ v6.
On the Queue Manager, we notice that the number of open channel connections keeps on growing, and appears as though the MDBs are not releasing these connections.
I am not aware of any errors happening in the onMessage method of the MDBs which could cause it to not exit cleanly.

Any advise on what could be causing this would be greatly appreciated
Thanks
Gavin

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue with WAS v7 connecting to WMQ V6 where MDBs do not reconnect.  The APAR mentions failures after a WMQ outage but other types of failure can result in similar behavior.

In general, the advice is to move to WMQ v7 since WMQ V6 is out of service as of September 2011.  The fix was released in v7.0.1.1 and later.  No v6 fix pack is listed for delivery of this APAR, although it doesn't mention why.  So if you cannot upgrade to v7.0.1.1 or later, then obtain via a PMR and apply IC64098 and see if that solves the problem.

References:
[PSP #1316899:](http://bit.ly/bSx9lc) Information about using the WebSphere MQ messaging provider for WebSphere Application Server Version 7.0
[IBM IC64098](http://bit.ly/IC64098): APPLICATION DOES NOT AUTOMATICALLY RECONNECT TO THE QUEUE MANAGER IF CONNECTION IS LOST WHEN USING THE MQ RESOURCE ADAPTER

Comment: Thank you for your response. The 2 references both take me to the IBM broken link page, so I was not able to get more information. In any case the problem you describe is not exactly what we are experiencing, although we have seen this problem also. The problem that we have is under normal circumstances (ie no MQ outage or the like) it appears that the MDBs are not closing the channel connections, and as a result we see the number of open channel connections growing. Is this also related to the same problem you described.

Comment: Odd, both of the links still work for me.  They are both bit.ly links so the targets are: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21316899 and http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC64098 respectively.  Although it looks like the MDB may not be closing its connections what may be happening is that connections are being orphaned and the MDB just opens a new one.  If that's the case, then the APAR both explains the behavior you are seeing and will probably help resolve it.

Comment: Can you please clarify whether this APAR is a patch that is applied to the Application Server or to the MQ Queue Manager. Also would you have any idea why the connections get orphaned. What is really strange, is that we are running the application in 2 environments, TEST and QA. In the TEST environment the channels remain static, however in QA, the channels keep on growing.

Comment: The APAR is not a patch (i.e. stand-alone fix), it was delivered in WMQ Fix Pack 7.0.1.1 and later. Reconciling open TCP sockets between the client and the server should tell you whether this is the culprit.  Or just apply WMQ Fix Pack 7.0.1.3 (the latest) from http://bit.ly/WMQFixes and see if it does not help. There were several APARs included since 7.0.1.1 that might apply here because v7 client channel protocol was significantly changed from v6 so go with 7.0.1.3 instead of 7.0.1.1.

Comment: Not sure why the connections are orphaned.  Lots of possible internal (app, app server) or external (network, firewall) possibilities for this behavior.  In general, you want to make sure to have tuned your channels with heartbeat and TCP Keepalive turned on so that the QMgr finds out quickly when this has happened.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade WMQ v7.0.1.1 or later version since this is a known issue with WAS v7 connecting to WMQ V6.